# python3: having problems with os.walk

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following directory/file setup (this is simplified):

```
Ce  
+---top.txt
+---X0.0        
|     |  
|     +---Y0.0  
|     |     |
|     |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.0.dat
|     |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.05.dat   
|     +---Y0.05
|           |
|           +---X0.0Y0.05Z0.0.dat
|           +---X0.0Y0.05Z0.05.dat
+---X0.05
      |  
      +---Y0.0  
      |     |
      |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.0.dat
      |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.05.dat   
      +---Y0.05
            |
            +---X0.0Y0.05Z0.0.dat
            +---X0.0Y0.05Z0.05.dat
```

Within each Y directory, I need to make a 'psub' file, which contains appends a list of the .dat files to a copy of the file 'top.txt'.

I am attempting to do this using the os.walk function in python 3: however I am incurring two problems:
1. The new psub file appears in the X0.0 directory
2. Code does not list any filenames (presumably because it is not finding any) and then gives the error that it is unable to find the X0.05 directory.

Thus far, I have the following code:

```
import os

with open('top.txt', 'r') as reader:
    data=reader.read()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        for folder in dirs:
            os.chdir(os.path.join(root, folder))
            with open('psub', 'a') as writer:
                writer.write(data)
                for names in files:
                    if names.endswith('.dat'):
                        print('gulp <' + names + '> ', end='', file=writer)
                        print(names.rsplit('.',1)[0], end='', file=writer)
                        print('.out', file=writer)
```

The resulting psub file should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
#MOAB -l walltime=48:00:0
#MOAB -j oe
#MOAB -N GULP-job
cd "$PBS_O_WORKDIR"
module load apps/gulp
#!/bin/bash
gulp <X0.00Y0.00Z0.00.dat> X0.00Y0.00Z0.00.out
gulp <X0.00Y0.00Z0.05.dat> X0.00Y0.00Z0.05.out
```

of which the first seven lines are in top.txt.

Any (simple) pointers as to where I am going wrong would be much appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: What do you think the code you have does? Your explanation of the function/purpose of the psub files is somewhat confusing; are they meant to serve as a directory listing for the files, as temporary storage while you collect the names of the files, or are they _already_ directories for the dat files? Going just from the explanation, they could just as well be executable files that append some kind of directory listing to `psubtry.txt`.

Comment: @AJMansfield the psub file will enable me to run a computational chemistry code (gulp) on a hpc system, reading the .dat files as the input.

Comment: @AJMansfield I thought the code should be 'walking' the directories: i.e. finding and folders in the top directory 'Ce' and then what files/folders are in the sub - directories. I can sort of see where the error of not finding the X0.05 directory comes from the line in which I change the directory, but otherwise am stumped (and possibly confused....)

Comment: And so you want to have one of these scripts in each Y directory? Ok, I get the question now.

Comment: `os.chdir` in the middle of iteration over `os.walk` is surely a bug.

Comment: @user4815162342 ok, so can os.walk not be used to go into a directory (and further sub-directories) and write a new file to them?

Comment: You don't need to `chdir` into a directory to write a new file there - simply use `os.path.join()` to concatenate the directory name with the trailing file name components. This is like in the shell: if `d1/d2` exists, you can create a file with `touch d1/d2/f` without ever cd-ing into `d1/d2`. If you absolutely must change the directory with `os.chdir` (although I don't see why you'd need to), then use `os.getcwd()` to remember the current directory, and return there with another `os.chdir()` when you're done. But there's no reason to do that, and it's only slowing down the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`walk` is meant to recursively iterate through all the directories by itself, so 
there is no need to iterate through all the subdirectories yourself. Get rid of the `for folder in dirs:` loop.

I'd also recommend replacing the multiple print statements with a single string format command, like so:

```
print('gulp <{}.dat> {}.out'.format(names.rsplit('.',1)[0]), file=writer)
#or use writer.write(), to make it more transparent
```

You should also rename some of the variables so that they better represent what they are used for; for instance calling the iterated variable in the last loop `names` is misleading, because it is not in fact a collection of names, but a single filename.

EDIT: To avoid creating extra empty files, you need to check if the directory needs a file created. You can do this by iterating through the filenames and setting a flag if any are a`.dat` file that needs processing.

EDIT 2: Factored code, and renamed a bunch of stuff, so now it is a lot clearer.

The sum of these modifications results in:

```
import os

def isDat(filename): return filename.endswith('.dat')

def hasDat(filenames): #this method checks if it contains one ending with '.dat'
    for filename in filenames:
        if isDat(filename): return true
    return false

def datFiles(filenames):
    for filename in filenames:
        if isDat(filename): yield filename

def gulpLines(filenames):
    for filename in datFiles(filenames):
        yield 'gulp <{}.dat> {}.out\n'.format(filename.rsplit('.',1)[0])

def makePsub(root, filenames, prologue):
    with os.open(os.path.join(root, 'psub'), 'a') as writer:
    #try putting 'psub.sh' instead, perhaps it is getting confused with no extension
        writer.write(prologue)
        for gulpLine in gulpLines(filenames):
            writer.write(gulpLine)


with open('top.txt') as reader:
    prologue=reader.read() #this is a much more descriptive name
#you can close it as soon as you have its contents

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    if hasDat(filenames):
        makePsub(root, filenames, prologue)
```

Python is meant to be made up of numerous small functions, not big long monstrosities nested twenty deep.

Additionally, by factoring out the code, you give yourself the ability to determine exactly what part of the code is causing the problems, because you can then test each function individually. If you suspect (for instance) that the problem is not being able to correctly recognize `.dat` files, you can test the `isDat` function by itself until you have fixed it. If you suspect that the issue is with writing to the `psub` file, you can check that by replacing `gulpLines` with a dummy implementation (where it uses a predetermined list of results, or has the user do it manually, rather than actually generating them).

The other thing you can do is insert debug code inside the loops. For instance, insert a statement that outputs the contents of `writer` after you (supposedly) write `data` to it, to check if you actually have what you expect to have there. Another debug option is to run partial code; for instance, run a program that only does the walk loop, or only writes `data` to the files, or only parses the filenames (printing what it *would* write to the files to the console, for inspection purposes).

Comment: this still doesn't work. A psub file appears in the Ce folder and in the first Y directory: both only contain the contents of top.txt.

Comment: @user2696225 Ok, fixed.

Comment: no. still doing the same thing. The code doesn't appear to get past going into the first X directory (where there are no .dat files). I have the os.walk('.') on its own (printing the results to screen) and this works. I know the rest of my code from the line with open(psub, 'a') as reader works (from previous use of it).